# Add text hook to products from specified category

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I would like to add some text by hook to products from category slug: "sizesukienki-plus-size"

I try this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'plussize');
 function plussize() 
 {
    if ( is_product_category() )
    {
if( is_product_category( 'sizesukienki-plus-size' ) )
{
echo '<p class="rtrn">Modne sukienki Plus Size to bez wątpienia jeden z obowiązkowych elementów garderoby wielu kobiet. Nadadzą się one na przeróżne okazje. Bez problemu można w nich wyjść do pracy, na spotkanie z przyjaciółmi, randkę czy komunię lub wesele.
</p>';
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The conditional Tag `is_product_category()` target product category archive pages… To  target product categories in single product pages you need to use WordPress conditional function `has_term()` this way:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_meta_end', 'plussize');
function plussize() {
    global $product;
    if( has_term( 'sizesukienki-plus-size', 'product_cat', $product->get_id() ) ) {
        echo '<p class="rtrn">' . __('Modne sukienki Plus Size to bez wątpienia jeden z obowiązkowych elementów garderoby wielu kobiet. Nadadzą się one na przeróżne okazje. Bez problemu można w nich wyjść do pracy, na spotkanie z przyjaciółmi, randkę czy komunię lub wesele.') . </p>';
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should work.